# Extract equally spaced points from a shapefile in R

Tags: r, extract, latitude-longitude, shapefile, points

I'm trying to extract evenly spaced points along a shapefile (line) in R where the line isn't necessarily contiguous (essentially extracting vertices, but equally spaced). I've seen similar questions asked elsewhere but not with an adequate answer e.g.

[[Generate regularly spaced points in polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547826/generate-regularly-spaced-points-in-polygon][1])

Process would be:
Read line shapefile and set crs
Calculate point every x spacing along line (e.g. every 1km)
Convert points to lat/long
Export

Has anyone done similar before/have some code that can do this?

Thank you

Comment: do you have a [small reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to share along with the code you are trying to use?

Comment: May be worth checking out these packages: • ggmap: extends the plotting package ggplot2 for maps
• rgdal: R’s interface to the popular C/C++ spatial data processing library gdal
• rgeos: R’s interface to the powerful vector processing library geos
• maptools: provides various mapping functions
• dplyr and tidyr: fast and concise data manipulation packages
• tmap: a new packages for rapidly creating beautiful maps

Comment: Nate, i don't have any code that can achieve the above at the moment unfortunately as i'm not sure what the best approach would be at this stage. Looking for some guidance as to how to approach this.